# jQuery .data vs eventData

Tags: jquery, events

When setting up a event handler (submit, click, keypress, whatever) what is the fastest and most efficient way to get data to the handler and use it in the handler? Should I be doing something like:

```
$obj.data({name: value, ...});

$obj.click(function(e){
  var $this = $(e.target),
    name = $this.data(name);
});
```

Or is it better to do something like this:

```
$obj.bind('click', {name: value}, function(e) {
  var $this = $(e.target),
    name = e.data.name;
});
```

Are there other considerations I am omitting?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Either way works, you're storing the same data in a *slightly* different spot, though your first can be less wasteful using [`$.data()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.data/) without creating a jQuery object, like this:

```
$obj.data({ name: value });
$obj.click(function(e) {
  var name = $.data(this, 'name');
});
```

Personally, I find the second much cleaner, it's equivalent version is shorter overall as well:

```
$obj.bind('click', {name: value}, function(e) {
   var name = e.data.name;
});
```

Comment: Yeah, I suppose for the example it was irrelevant, I just cut it out of my code where I find I am almost always creating it.

Answer (score 4):

Essentially the same thing, but even a little cleaner with [.click](http://api.jquery.com/click/) (added in [jQuery 1.4.3](http://blog.jquery.com/2010/10/16/jquery-143-released/)):

```
$obj.click({name: value}, function(e) {
    var name = e.data.name;
});
```

Answer (score 3):

A little late but perhaps usefull for someone.

I would say it depends. If your data is final at the creation of the event handler (or a object, which you can reach from other areas of your code) the second method is fine.

On the other hand, if you use the $.data() function you will always reference to the actual data. If the data might be changed before the event is fired.

Answer (score 0):

There is another method, it is better because you can access to data properties via 'this' clause:

```
        var tst = {
            a:1, 
            b:2, 
            clickHandler: function(e) {
                alert(this.a);
                alert($(e.target).attr('id'));
            }
        };

        $('#btn').click(tst.clickHandler.bind(tst));
```